# onWindowFocusChanged() gets invoked more than once when i resume the app from the homescreen or appDrawer

Tags: android, homescreen, resume

the following is my **console output** of what happens when i move to the homescreen from the app and then move back to the app from the homescreen

HOME BUTTON PRESSED TO MINIMIZE THE APPLICATION

```
: onWindowFocusChanged() -> hasFocus:false
```

APPLICATION BUTTON PRESSED TO RETURN TO THE RUNNING APPLICATION

```
: onWindowFocusChanged() -> hasFocus:true
: mySimpleSoundPlaybackMethods()
```

Now the windowFocus has already become true... then why should the following occur **again**???

```
: onWindowFocusChanged() -> hasFocus:false
: onWindowFocusChanged() -> hasFocus:true
: mySoundPlaybackMethods()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw a complete guess into the ring ... maybe because whatever you're touching has focus when the application resumes?  (again, complete guess)  App gets focus then transfers to your touch event then back to app.

Comment: so... how do i remove the focus when the application resumes